# sql using group by for more than just a table

Tags: sql

I am trying to to get for all the departments, their location,number of employees, and the average  salary. I have tried something like this but I've got a "not a group by expression" error:

```
 SELECT d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, l.CITY, count(e.FIRST_NAME), avg(e.SALARY)
   FROM DEPARTMENTS d, LOCATIONS l, EMPLOYEES e
  WHERE d.DEPARTMENT_ID = e.DEPARTMENT_ID
    AND d.LOCATION_ID = l.LOCATION_ID
  GROUP BY d.department_id, l.LOCATION_ID, e.DEPARTMENT_ID;
```

I have never used group by on multiple tables so if anyone could explain how to use it or what I am doing wrong I would be more than grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the non-aggregate fields in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Try this way:

```
 SELECT d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, l.CITY, count(e.FIRST_NAME), avg(e.SALARY)
   FROM DEPARTMENTS d, LOCATIONS l, EMPLOYEES e
  WHERE d.DEPARTMENT_ID = e.DEPARTMENT_ID
    AND d.LOCATION_ID = l.LOCATION_ID
  GROUP BY d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, l.CITY
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct SQL should be:

```
 SELECT d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, l.CITY, count(e.FIRST_NAME), avg(e.SALARY)
   FROM DEPARTMENTS d, LOCATIONS l, EMPLOYEES e
  WHERE d.DEPARTMENT_ID = e.DEPARTMENT_ID
    AND d.LOCATION_ID = l.LOCATION_ID
  GROUP BY d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, l.CITY;
```

Why:

Because every non aggregate columns in select list must be included in `GROUP BY` clause. Here non aggregate columns are `d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, l.CITY` hence the `GROUP BY` is `d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, l.CITY`